# Необходимо сгрупировать по заданому столбцу и посчитать средний процент отклонения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Материалы являются индексом. Необходимо сгрупировать по поставщику и посчитать по нему среднее отклонение.

Исходный DataFrame выглядит следующим образом:

```
Материалы                  Поставщик                                   Отклонение
Алебастр 5кг                ФОРПОСТ                                     18.00 %
Атмосфера (60м2)            ФОРПОСТ                                     27.36 %
Бур 6*160 по бетону         Стройбаза-Спектр                            5.02 %
Валик 100мм                 Стройбаза-Спектр                            3.04 %
Валик 240мм                 Электротехническая компания                 3.29 %
```

И еще много различных позиций материалов и поставщиков.

Получить хотелось бы следующее:

```
Поставщик                          Среднее отклонение
Форпост                            22 %
Стройбаза-Спектр                   4.01 %
Электротехническая компания        3 %
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.groupby("Поставщик")["Отклонение"].mean().reset_index()
```